# Why can't change my destktop from mate into others?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, cinnamon, lxde, mate-desktop

I have installed many desktop environments on my debian8.1 such as cinnamon, mate, lxde, xfce.

I found that I can't select the desktop as I like ,whichever I choose, the desktop is always mate when to login in my debian8.1.

[image]
[image]

It is no use to choose lxde in the menu, I have tested it many times and other desktop such as cinnamon.
How to change the default setting to make mate as default desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the display manager.
If that does not work, install a different display manager.
This will force debconf to reconfigure the display manager to be used.